# Xpath stuck in while loop?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I need to check xml feeder updated date and updated date from my database and get just updated date that are not exists in my database. 
I am doing that because i need to get just odds changes from last time that parser start.

But there is problem it's stuck and nothing happened, just loading page, all day.

Here is code:

```
    $updDate = $this->PDO->prepare("select distinct FixtureMatch_Id,UpdatedDate from odds");
    $updDate->execute();
    $updDate->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     while($row = $updDate->fetch()){
        $odds=$this->soccer->GetAllOddsByFixtureMatchId(
        array("fixtureMatch_Id"=>$row['FixtureMatch_Id']))
            ->xpath("//Odds[not(contains(UpdatedDate,$row['UpdatedDate']))]");

        echo $row['FixtureMatch_Id'] . ' : ' . $row['UpdatedDate'] . '<br>';
        }

     }
```

this is how it looks when i var dump without xpath like this:

```
$odds=$this->soccer->GetAllOddsByFixtureMatchId(
        array("fixtureMatch_Id"=>$row['FixtureMatch_Id']))->OddsList->Odds;
```

xml

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[11]
public 'FixtureMatch_Id' => string '325006' (length=6)
public 'Bookmaker' => string 'Pinnacle' (length=8)
public 'UpdatedDate' => string '2015-05-23T14:58:51.213' (length=23)
public 'Type' => string 'Over/Under 2.5' (length=14)
public 'HomeOdds' => string '1.85' (length=4)
public 'AwayOdds' => string '2.08' (length=4)
```

Update: In database is abount 16000 rows in odds table, is it problem?

Comment: What kind of value does `$row['UpdatedDate']` bear? I guess your xpath needs single quotes around it so that `contains` work as expected.

Comment: It is datetime in this format 2015-06-17 19:40:49

I think that main problem is in 16000 rows from db that i want to check, i just want to get different updated dates, there is just few different dates, but it is searchin whole xml i guess...

Comment: It is same with quotes "//Odds[UpdatedDate='$row[FixtureMatch_Id]']", same is when i do it like this "//Odds[UpdatedDate='2015-06-13T12:30:00']"